# SmartGWT - Cannot change configuration property "x" after the component created

Tags: components, smartgwt, treegrid

From this example http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_databinding_local , I started to implement my own tree structure dynamically (TreeGrid). When I try to render it, I get this error (title).

```
public class ProjectTreeGridScreen extends Screen {

  Tree tree;

  @Override
  protected void onLoad() {
    super.onLoad();

    TreeGrid treeGrid = new TreeGrid();

    setPageTitle(Util.C.projectListTitle());

    treeGrid.setWidth(600);
    treeGrid.setHeight(400);

    TreeGridField projectTree = new TreeGridField("ProjectName", "Project Tree");
    TreeGridField projectPath = new TreeGridField("ProjectPath", "Complete path");
    TreeGridField projectDescription = new TreeGridField("ProjectDescription", "Description");
    TreeGridField projectInfo = new TreeGridField("ProjectInfo", "Information");

    treeGrid.setFields(projectTree, projectPath, projectDescription, projectInfo);

    treeGrid.setData(tree);

    add(treeGrid);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onInitUI() {
    super.onInitUI();
    tree = new Tree();

    tree.setModelType(TreeModelType.PARENT);
    tree.setNameProperty("ProjectName");
    tree.setIdField("ProjectItem");
    tree.setParentIdField("ProjectParent");

    tree.setShowRoot(true);

    populateProjects();

  }

  protected void populateProjects() {

    Util.PROJECT_SVC.visibleProjects(
        new ScreenLoadCallback<List<Project>>(this) {
      @Override
      public void preDisplay(final List<Project> result) {
        tree.setData(ProjectTreeGridBuilder.fromRepositories(result));
      }
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Show the actual error complete error message, it's important, that's why the framework shows it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean by **"x"**? Normally, If a component has been drawn on the window (implicit or explicit call to draw), you cannot change it's properties values. So the only possible solution is to recreate the object with the new **X** value each time it is changing.

Comment: That's what I did thx. I didn't posted my solution. I create my window (add function) each time I finished fetching my data from server. I wanted to populate my data to my grid when fetching my data, but I guess you can't do that...

Comment: Do not forget the fact that your code is transformed into javascript which isn't as powerful as java. So, you will find it difficult to do certain things if you are trying to implement it the java way (I had these problems too :P)